# maven build expecting wrong version of jar

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-2, pom.xml

I am doing a maven build and its getting failed since the maven is referring to wrong version

[pom.xml definition for lombok dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9jXb.png)

When i am building , its  failing with below reason .Could not find artifact org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:${lombok.version} , not sure why its referring to lombok.version when we given the version 1.18.4

And this started recently all of sudden .

Can some one able to help me

Comment: The dependency declaration looks good. Not sure what is the problem. Would it build if you set the following?

    <properties>
        <lombok.version>1.18.4</lombok.version>
    </properties>

If yes, then check the other projects you are depending on - are they requiring the lombok.version variable to be set?

Comment: I tried like this in my maven settings.xml <profile>
        <id>lombokversion</id>
        <properties>
            <lombok.version>1.18.4</lombok.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>, but it did not workout for me

Comment: You could double-check by running mvn dependency:tree and checking where lombok.version comes from. It must appear in the output of that command somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some place either in your POM, or your parent POM or maybe a dependency where the version of lombok is defined as `<version>${lombok.version}</version>`.

This causes the problem.

Comment: we did not defined any where lombok.version in our dependencies. I verified multiple times

Comment: Maven does not invent the `${lombok.version}` string, it must be somewhere in the POMs.